# Indicar al usuario que está usando mal una función

Tags: java

No sé si lo que quiero hacer es posible o no, pero al menos, no he encontrado forma con throw ni throws.

Tengo una función que pide un byte y solo lo devuelve si está dentro de un rango determinado, esta es la función:

```
    public byte readByteInRangeInclusive(byte lowerBound, byte upperBound) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Devuelve un byte introducido por el usuairo que esté entre los dos números introducidos.
        // Ambos números incluidos.
        // Se ha filtrado el uso equívoco de los valores mínimos y máximos en la función por el uso del usuario.

        byte n = 0;
        boolean condition = false;

        if (lowerBound > upperBound) {
            // Si lower es mayor que upper se invierten los parámetros.

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El primer número no puede ser mayor al segundo");
        }

        do {
            n = readByte();

            if (n >= lowerBound && n <= upperBound) {
                condition = true;
            } else {
                System.out.printf("El número no está en el rango entre %d y %d\n", lowerBound, upperBound);
            }
        } while (!condition);

        return n;
    }
```

La función readByte(), le pide al usuario un byte y comprueba que efectivamente, sea un byte y no un int o un caracter.

Lo que quiero hacer es que el compilador de java (estoy usando eclipse) me diga que si en la función readByteInRangeInclusive() el primer número es mayor al segundo, sarte un error del tipo "No estás haciendo esto bien o algo así?

¿Se puede hacer?

Gracias.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que necesitas. Quieres que si el primer parámetro es mayor que el segundo, lance una excepción diciendo que no puede ser así. Y ya has creado dicha excepción. ¿Te da algún error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que entendí de tu consulta: si lowBound > upperBound tiene que lanzar un mensaje de error para que se sepa que esta mal.

> Excepciones: Java maneja las excepciones de forma tal que cuando se quiere señalar que va a haber un error se "lanza" (throw) una excepcion y luego se "atrapa" (catch) desde donde se ejecuta dicho metodo. Cuando se entra a la excepcion el programa se detiene, se pueden ejecutar sentencias luego del error con finally. Como se usa. En tu ejemplo lanzas una excepción (que supongo que tenes programada). Lo que faltaria es atraparla.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
 //hay que recordar que si entra en la excepcion el programa se detiene, asi que hay 
 //que evitar entrar en la misma, a menos que quieras que se cierre el programa.
 //Se puede controlar con un if 
if(lowerBound<upperBound){
  try{
    readByteInRangeInclusive(lowerBound,upperBound);
  }catch(IllegalArgumentExceptione){
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 }else
   System.out.println("lowerBound>= que upperBound, vuelva a ingresar los valores, 
     pero esta vez, bien ");
  }
```

> Con este ejemplo por ahi no se ve muy bien la importancia de las excepciones, pero cuando trabajas con estructuras que usan otras estructuras te es indispensable.
>
> Si no tenes programada la excepción se hace así.(es una clase a parte)

```
public class IllegalArgumentException extends Exception{
  public IllegalArgumentException(String msg){
  super(msg);
  }
}
```